# Is there any way to feed a file to a MediaSource Analyser Node

Tags: javascript, fft, media-source

I'd like to test whether some FFT analysis code I am writing in Python is exactly the same implementation as the Javascript MediaSource FFT node. (See example here [Web Audio API Analyser Node Not Working With Microphone Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231265/web-audio-api-analyser-node-not-working-with-microphone-input)).

I have read the specs but I'd prefer to do a test.  I want to push the same exact snippet of audio through both, and then get the output and do a diff.

Is there anyway to hook up Javascript to a local file instead of a microphone? likely WAV format 48kHz

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData Also, [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) belongs to an other API, which to my knowledge doesn't have an *Analyser Node*.

Comment: Sweet Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

1. Create an AudioElement.
2. Set the `src` property to the blob URL for your MediaSource.
3. [Create a new MediaElementAudioSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource), with the AudioElement.
4. Connect that node to your AnalyserNode.
5. Make sure the AnalyserNode is connected to some output, even if muted by way of GainNode.